# Regex for alphanumeric only that checks entire word

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test("$tr!ng") //false
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test("string") //false
```

both the expression above returns false.

I need regex which returns true if whole word contains only alphanumeric characters.
Can you point out what mistake I am doing in above expression

Comment: use + to match 1 or more characters. Right now you're only matching 1 character so the test fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to add any kind of repeating modifier to your regex. You need to add a `*` to specify that the alphanumeric character can appear multiple times before the end of the string:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

Comment: Not sure empty string should return 'true'.

Comment: There's certainly an argument to be made that it shouldn't. I used the first multiplier that came to mind. I don't have the requirements, so I don't know for sure.